# Do something only on distinct XML nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I'm having hard times in triggering an xsl action only on distinct values. Here's an excerpt of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Doc Data="February 2010">
  <Title>Title 1</Title> 
  <Subject>Subject 1</Subject> 
</Doc>
<Doc Data="January 2010">
  <Title>Title 2</Title> 
  <Subject>Subject 2</Subject> 
</Doc>
<Doc Data="January 2010">
  <Title>Title 3</Title> 
  <Subject>Subject 3</Subject> 
</Doc>
```

And this is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                xmlns:objUtility="urn:utility"
                version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="Doc">
    <xsl:if test="not(@Data = preceding-sibling::Doc/@Data)">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Data" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:apply-templates />
```

The problem is that, with this code, the preceding-sibling::Doc/@Data element always contains ONLY THE FIRST element, so basically I get a distinct value only for February and not for January. Where am I wrong? I must use XSL 1.0

Comment: Your code sample works for me, printing `"February 2010"` and `"January 2010"`.

Comment: Really odd, I get every element instead (february tested against nothing, and both january tested against february)...

Comment: I don't see any problem with your stylesheet snippet but if you have something not working as intended then it is better to supply minimal but complete samples that allow others to reproduce the problem. Do you really have a fragment as posted as your input? How does the complete stylesheet look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to ask “Is there any preceding sibling of type Doc with a Data attribute equal to the Data attribute of the current node?”, the XPath for that should look like

```
<xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::Doc[@Data = current()/@Data])">
```